The solana rpc node we deployed ourselves cannot work stably
Problem

We have deployed a solana rpc node locally specifically for internal use of the team.
This node will work normally for a while. However, after this node has been running for a period of time, the listening on port 8899 will be closed.
Below is the command line I use to start this node

#!/bin/bash
exec solana-validator \
    --identity /solana/validator-keypair.json \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --no-voting \
    --ledger /solana/ledger \
    --log /solana/logs/solana.log \
    --accounts /solana/accounts \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
    --private-rpc \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --limit-ledger-size \
    --no-snapshot-fetch


Hardware

cpu 16x
RAM 128G
Disk ssd 2T


When the RPC service is stopped, the following log will appear

[2024-04-19T03:23:14.846220992Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils::snapshot_storage_rebuilder] rebuilt storages for 316227/409524 slots with 0 collisions
[2024-04-19T03:31:36.870598456Z INFO  solana_accounts_db::accounts_db] generating index: 33897/428024 slots... (408/s)

What configuration needs to be modified so that this node can provide long-term and stable services?
